# Is it possible to cancel or dispose of an AdMob interstitial ad pre-load?

Tags: cordova, admob

I am adding AdMob Interstitial adds to my Android Cordova app.  I preload the ad with this call during a natural break in the game:

```
if(AdMob) AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {adId:admobid.interstitial, autoShow:false} );
```

But, if the user navigates to the next screen and replays the game, and the ad is still pre-loading in the background, it obviously affects the performance of the app.  My app is about exact timing, so this ruins the game.

So, I would like to cancel the pre-load or dispose of it somehow, but I do not see this sort of option in the AdMob API.  Another option would be to prevent the player from navigating to the next screen until a certain amount of time has passed, but there is no timeout option for AdMob preload either.

The exact plugin I am using is 'cordova-plugin-admobpro': https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

Comment: Which plugin are you using? And why don't you prepare the interstitial ahead of time?

Comment: I am using the latest 'cordova-plugin-admobpro'.  I'm not sure where else I could prepare ahead of time.  From what I have read, I am supposed to call Admob.prepareInterstitial each time I want to serve up a new add.  As mentioned, I can't have it preloading while the game is playing as it negatively affects performance.  So I call the preload function after each round on the round summary screen.  The amount of time it takes to preload is indeterminant, so how can I assure no preloading is happening during gameplay?

Answer (score 2):

I am using https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

From their docs

> If you already called admob.requestInterstitialAd() but the
>   interstitial has never been shown, the following calls to
>   admob.requestInterstitialAd() will result in the ad being inmediately
>   available (the one that was obtained in the first call).

One of my apps is a puzzle game, it takes players on average 30 seconds per puzzle. **I load the interstitial on loading the puzzle**, and display just after the win screen when the user clicks "Next" to load the next puzzle.

FYI, I am using a minimum threshold time between display one interstitial and the next so it's not shown after every win.